# nodejs remove a file: TypeError: promises_1.rm is not a function

Tags: node.js

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_rm_path_options) for removing a file say that it should be imported the same as [readfile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_rm_path_options) as far as I understand it.

am I missing something?

in my code I have:

```js
import { readFile, rm } from 'fs/promises'

export async function foo () {
  try {
    const res = await readFile('./file.txt') // works
    await rm('./file.txt') // TypeError: promises_1.rm is not a function
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('er', e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Node? `readFile` was added in v10.0.0, `rm` only in v14.14.0.

Comment: yea that was the issue. I thought that it would have been added sooner. so I will use unlink

Answer (score 8):

as @jonrsharpe said in the comment the issue is the node version. Since `rm` was added with version `14.14.0` and I am on `14.13.0`

Comment: Then why on earth it's in `.d.ts` file for `14.13.0`? Is there a bug report somewhere?